# Problem with pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex and math in column name

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I am creating a group plot, in which individual plots are added via a macro that pulls data from a text file. This is the macro that adds a plot and legend entries:

```
\newcommand{\plotFourFactorCombis}[1]{

\pgfplotstabletranspose[
colnames from=NbOfChangesApplied,
columns={NbOfChangesApplied,0,4,8,12}
]\loadedtable{#1}

\foreach \n in {1,2} {
    \addplot table[x index=0,y index=\n]{\loadedtable};
    \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\n}\of{\loadedtable}\to{\colname}
    \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
    }%
}
```

The tab-separated text file would look like:

```
NbOfChangesApplied  0  4  8  12
{$MAPD^{z^{\text{PBC}}}$}   0   7   14  16
{$MAPD^{z^{\text{DPM}}}$}   0   9   10  22
```

A compilation error is caused by `\text`. When I remove `\text` there is no compilation error.

Is there a way to support math commands, such as `\text`, inside macros?

Comment: +1 for the function name longer than the rest of the question title put together.

Comment: No idea, anybody? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, manual legend entry outside the macro does the trick:

```
    \nextgroupplot [
    legend entries={$MAPD^{z^{\text{PBC}}}$,$MAPD^{z^{\text{DPM}}}$},
    legend style={
        legend to name=grouplegendA,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend columns=2,
        },
    ]
\plotFourFactorCombis{data.txt}
```